# SQL Parentheses Priority

Tags: sql, t-sql, boolean

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 and trying to do a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM finance WHERE paid > 1000 and not (city <> 'RJ' and (flag2 is null or flag2 = '0'))
```

But i'm not getting the desire solution.

My idea is to search all payments bigger then 1.000 and excludes people who lives in "RJ" AND the flag is 0. If the person lives in RJ but the flag2 is 1, should appear.
So, I only want to exclude rows with people from 'RJ' and FLAG2 = '1'

One example, In my head, the logic is:

```
SELECT * FROM finance WHERE paid > 1000 and not (FALSE and (flag2 is null or flag2 = '0'))
SELECT * FROM finance WHERE paid > 1000 and not (FALSE and TRUE)
SELECT * FROM finance WHERE paid > 1000 and not (FALSE and TRUE)
SELECT * FROM finance WHERE paid > 1000 and not (FALSE)
SELECT * FROM finance WHERE paid > 1000 and (TRUE)
```

But it's not working like this.
What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The translation of your logic is more like:

```
SELECT *
FROM finance 
WHERE paid > 1000 and not (city = 'RJ' and flag = 0)
```

I find the double negative (`not` with `<>`) to be a bit hard to follow.

This is equivalent to:

```
WHERE paid > 1000 and (city <> 'RJ' or (flag <> 0 or flag is null))
```

Answer (score 0):

IN Boolean logic NOT AND NOT is written as NOT OR NOT

```
and not (city <> 'RJ' OR (flag2 is null or flag2 = '0'))
```